Name of song from Young Justice League season 2 episode 5
A female voice sings, the song conveys the atmosphere of ancient times. The song is in the style of mythical Greek and epic, in the spirit of Justice League. I heard this song in one video, it was called "Marvel vs Mortal Kombat vs DC", but the user deleted the video. But there is a fragment of it in the animated series Young Justice at 11:30-11:40. Please help, Shazam is not helping https://youtube.com/shorts/Z7W5Pvm0zQ4?si=xW8AiADWeR1zyiOg

If it's not in the official soundtrack, the snipped could only be a soundeffect to convey the "ancient atmosphere". Did you hear a full song in the deleted video? Did you check the official soundtrack?

It was a complete song, but not very popular. She was listed in the video, I even found her on YouTube in 2017-2018. The name was “apocalypse” or “war” and so on. There was epic music and singing. So the song exists. We just need to find her somehow...

I found it. Ikarus - Deep Inside




Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.
